# How do i listen for dismiss event inside Model Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

I have one .ts file for model. I want to execute some code when this model is dismissed(from model file itself).

All examples are about `onDidDismiss()` method which is written in model caller .ts file.I mean i have some db listeners in my model .ts file.

What i am trying to do is unsubscribe them when user dismisses the model window by clicking outside of model window.

Answer (score 2):

You can use below method in your Model page :

```
dismiss() {
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
  }
```

and in this method you can write your code.

Ref Link : https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/tree/v3/demos/src/modal

Ionic Ref : https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/modal/ModalController/

Hope this will helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can publish event inside of `onDidDismiss()` and subscribe event from where you want.

Your modal page ts file:

```
import { ....., Events } from 'ionic-angular';

constructor(....,public events:Events){.....}

modal.onDidDismiss(()=>{
 this.events.publish("modal:dismissed","data what you want to publish",Date.now());
})
```

subscription from anywhere:
    import and inject again `Events` like in your modal ts file then;

```
this.events.subscribe('modal:dismissed', (value, publishTime) => {
 //enter your code here
});
```